# How to use preg_match to not allow space in the front and in the end, but allow in between

Tags: php, preg-match

I have looked around, and I found a lot of tutorials out there. But none of them could help in my case.
Here is my script:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]+$/',$user_name)) {
  echo"bad username";
}
```

This code not allow any spaces no matter what if they´re in the front, the end or in between.

I want to allow just between but not in the front and in the end.

Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: If you want to check whether the first and/or last characters in a string are spaces, you could also use string functions like `strpos` or `substr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit you have

```
[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]
```

matches any of those characters the `+` means one or more.  If you want to match those or a space, simply add a space to the list, and place one grouping before and after the existing one, like so:

```
/^[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%][0-9A-Za-z!@#$% ]+[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]$/
```

A side effect of this will be that the username must be at least 3 characters long.  If you want to permit smaller usernames, you could split the check:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[0-9A-Za-z!@#$% ]+$/',$user_name) || preg_match('/^ /',$user_name) || preg_match('/ $/',$user_name)) {
```

the `!preg_match('/^[0-9A-Za-z!@#$% ]+$/',$user_name)` makes sure the username only contains approved characters, the `preg_match('/^ /',$user_name)` checks to see if it starts with a space, and the `preg_match('/ $/',$user_name)` checks to see if it ends with a space.

If you want to accept what was entered, and automatically remove any leading or trailing spaces, use the `trim` function.

Answer (score 2):

Use trim instead to omit white spaces in the left and right of your text.

```
<?php
$username = trim($username);

//your code...
?>
```

Comment: I was going to suggest that 5 minutes ago, but he wants he preg_match to still allow spaces in between and right now it doesn't. That doesn't really solve his regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
/^[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]++(?>[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%\s]+[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]+)?+$/
```

or this if you want to allow empty strings

```
/^(?>[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]+(?>[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%\s]*[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]+)?+)?+$/
```

Comment: Actually Casimir et Hippolyte´s answer (the last one) is also work perfect. But I respect Joe who gave me the answer first and have a lot of explaination. But thanks both of you. I appreciated it.